# How can I overload the compare operator for a set of pairs?

Tags: c++, set, overloading, comparator, std-pair

How can I overload and pass a `<` (less than) comparator to a set of pairs of integers? This is my current code:

```
class A{
public:
    typedef std::pair<int, int> pair_type;  

    bool operator<(const pair_type& a, const pair_type& b){ 
        if (a.first < b.first) return true;
        else if ( (a.first == b.first) && (a.second < b.second) ) return true;
        else return false;
    }

private:
    std::set< pair_type > edge_;
};
```

If I try to compile this code, then I get the following error:

```
error: 'bool A::operator<(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)' must take exactly one argument
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `std::pair` already has an appropriate [operator<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class A{
public:
    typedef std::pair<int, int> pair_type;  

    struct compare {
        bool operator()(const pair_type& a, const pair_type& b) {
          if (a.first < b.first) return true;
          else if ( (a.first == b.first) && (a.second < b.second) ) return true;
          else return false;
        }   
    };

  private:
    std::set<pair_type, compare> edge_;
};
```

Comment: Why do we have to put the operator inside an structure ?

Answer (score 5):

You should be definining the operator overload as a class member (with a single parameter, usually another instance of the same class):

```
class pair_type : public std::pair<int, int>
{
public:
    bool operator<(const pair_type &comp) const
    {
        if (this->first < comp.first) return true;
        else if ( (this->first == comp.first) && (this->second < comp.second) ) return true;
        else return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Comparison operators should never be member functions. The most appropriate technique is to declare it as a "friend" operator taking two arguments of the same type.

Comment: @Kastorskij Ah, thanks, you're right. I must admit to using the member function version more often, but it does make sense to use the friend function as explained in more detail here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633059/comparing-objects-using-bool-operator)

Answer (score 2):

Your operator should be free function (not member-function), since it has no any relations to `A` class.

Answer (score 2):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparator struct:

```
using pair_type = std::pair<int, int>;

auto comp = [](const pair_type& a, const pair_type& b) {
    return (a.first < b.first) || ((a.first == b.first) && (a.second < b.second));
};
```

I also compacted your comparator code in order to save two lines. Now, you can define your set in the following way:

```
std::set<pair_type, decltype(comp)> edge_(comp);
```

However, if you want to use the above comparator for a set which is a class member, then it's a bit less comfortable, because you have to pass the comparator also to the [constructor of the set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set), as shown above.
This means, you have to hand over the comparator in the initializer list of the constructor definition:

```
class A{
public:
    A() : edge_(comp) {}

private:
    std::set<pair_type, decltype(comp)> edge_;
};
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/2DVqKX)